# Fixing position of particular bar after sorting - Plotly Bar Graph

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I would like to know if it's possible to move the 'Total' Bar to the bottom or top of the figure after performing the sort using plotly.express bar.

Move 'Total' bar to the top or bottom after sorting:
[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYrK7.png)]

The sorting is performed using the following:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(sheet, y=sheet.index, x=rows, orientation='h')
fig = fig.update_layout(yaxis={'categoryorder':'total ascending'})
```

I have searched Stackoverflow and other platforms and could not find any related query.

Comment: Where is your code ? you use what go or px ?

Comment: Assuming `sheet` is a dataframe, why not just sort the data as desired using pandas?